# sending thousands of firebase push notifications with dynamic message

Tags: node.js, laravel, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've this case when I have to send message to collection of devices using their tokens but I want to put user name or some data that related to the user (variable) in the body of the notification like

`Dear %name% you got degree %degree%`

The problem now that I've to send a notification request to each user that's mean if I have 100k user => 100k request

Now I'm using Redis queue for the sending but I want to know if there is better way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how it is used together with Redis, but at last look into it:

Make sure that you send your messages in batches. Build lists of 500 individual messages and send those using e.g. `sendAll()` from the FCM admin SDK.

Stating the obvious: 100k messages will be 200 requests.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-a-batch-of-messages